# Google Sheets QUERY function - How to populate only a single cell with sum()? label doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've done some research but it wasn't satisfactory so I hope you can help me out here.

I have a table for my expenses which I typed manually inro Google Sheets:

| Date | Name | Category | Debits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/18/2022 | Trader Joe's | Groceries | $47.06 |
| 7/23/2022 | Hola Tacos | Restaurants | $80.00 |
| 7/24/2022 | Eversourse | Utilities | $36.00 |
| 8/24/2022 | New Tires | Transportation | $53.00 |
| 8/29/2022 | New Deli | Restaurants | $80.00 |
| 8/26/2022 | Costco | Groceries | $93.00 |
| 9/31/2022 | Tooth Paste | Wellness | $100.00 |

I'm trying to calculate the sum of all expenses for each month using this QUERY() function:

```
=QUERY($A$2:$D, CONCATENATE("select SUM(D) Where NOT A is Null AND MONTH(A)+1=",MONTH(F5)), 0)
```

where I typed the value into cell `F5` manually.

So I'm trying to get something like this ('July 2022' is cell 'F5'):

| July 2022 | August 2022 | September 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $163.00 | $226.00 | $65.00 |

, but the QUERY() function's output looks like this:

| July 2022 | August 2022 | September 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sum | sum | sum |
| $163.00 | $226.00 | $65.00 |

**Problem 1:** What I want is to avoid this new 'sum' row. So I tried to fix it with a `label SUM(D) ''` inside the query so it would look like this:

```
=QUERY($A$2:$D, CONCATENATE("select SUM(D) label SUM(D) '' Where NOT A is Null AND MONTH(A)+1=",MONTH(F5)), 0)
```

but it gives me a `#VALUE!` error:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2:
> PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "where" "Where "" at line 1, column 31. Was
> expecting one of:  "format" ... "options" ... "," ...

**Problem 2:** I have an issue with the month of September, the sum for it specifically is empty although I have values for this month in my table in the Debits column.

**Problem 3:** How can I calculate the sum of expenses per month for each category that exists in m this table?

Here's my document available online. Please, let me know how I can fix these issues.

[Dummy Budget](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ytpQzXweJd0Fut3GFRRrBcNhp4dB4lFXjnrNM9jnB7I/edit?usp=sharing)

Maybe there are other ways to calculate this but they seemed too difficult to me when I searched and tried to implement them by myself.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Problem 1: You can wrap Query formula with INDEX and get only second row of Query result: =index(Query(....sum something....),2) .

Comment: For problem3: You can also use Query formula for it. Try:  =QUERY({A2:D,arrayformula(month(A2:A))},"select Col5, sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col5 pivot Col3",0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### problem #1

Try

```
=QUERY($A$2:$D, "select SUM(D) Where NOT A is Null AND MONTH(A)+1="&MONTH(F5)&" label SUM(D) ''", 0)
```

### problem #2

for september, this is not a valid date `9/31/2022`, sept has 30 days! and `9/27/2022` seems also to be invalid (I have typed it again)

Why not using a pivot table and group the dates by year-month ?

[image]

### problem #3

the pivot table will be a good use for that
[image]